# Angular cli broccoli plugin error

Tags: npm, angular, angular-cli

I'm on windows 7 and trying to create sample project with angular-cli. I created a project with `ng new Test2` which successfully created the project but when i run, `ng serve`, it gives following errors.

```
The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler] failed with: operation not permitted.
```

Any idea what is going wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that the command prompt was **not running with administrator access**. So i just ran it with administrator access and ta da, it works.